# Summing two similar columns from csv file

Tags: linux

I'm using a very simple command in order to sort a list of Operators:

```
cut -d',' -f11 be_sendsms.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
95 "BASE17BE"
530 "BASE18BE"
252 "ORANGE17BE"
820 "ORANGE18BE"
162 "PROXIMUS17BE"
482 "PROXIMUS18BE"
```

Is there a simple way to accumulate the value of 'BASE17BE' and 'BASE18BE' so that their total appears together under 'BASE', and do the same for Orange and Proximus?

Answer (score 0):

We can redirect the output to a temp file and then apply the command given in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242946/using-awk-to-sum-the-values-of-a-column-based-on-the-values-of-another-column) answer

`awk -F ' ' '$2 ~ /BASE/ {sum += $1} END {print sum}' temp`